# Why can't I access the updated prop value within my function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So I have a functional component that gets data from redux. My issue is, I'm not able to access the current value of a certain prop, though the data is changing correctly in the redux store so it isn't an issue with redux, I don't think.

I rewrote a simple version of my component below. Oddly enough, even returning the value .toString() in my component jsx returns the correct value so I'm hoping this is just some scope issue or something I'm not getting about my code that is not getting me the correct value.

```
const Player = ({ isPlaying }) => {

  function setProgress() {
    console.log(isPlaying) // returns false here continuously!
  }

  function playSong() {
    setInterval(() => {
      setProgress();
    }, 500);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isPlaying) // returns true here!
  }, [isPlaying])
}


const mapStateToProps = ({ isPlaying }) => {
  console.log(isPlaying); // also returns true here!
  return { isPlaying };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Player);
```

Here is a link to a CodeSandbox recreation of the problem I have.

https://codesandbox.io/s/playererrordemo-r6bt2

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` creates a closure over `isPlaying`, that's why it's always the same value.

The interval keeps the reference to the value of `isPlaying`, it was called with. To change that you might need to `clearInterval` and start a new one when `isPlaying` changes.

Comment: This is still returning false when I log it to the console, and still returning true in the other places I noted in the question.

Comment: Where are you calling `playSong`?

Comment: I'm calling playSong in another useEffect within this component where I'm waiting for another prop passed to this component to change. The function fires correctly and updates all the data correctly in the redux store, I'm just not getting access to the updated values in the methods :(

Comment: I updated the answer. You'll need to clear the interval and start a new one when `isPlaying` changes.

Comment: I do that already in my code, I just didn't write it here because it doesn't seem relevant to my issue. I also tried a console log of isPlaying outside of the setInterval after updating it in my redux store and it's still giving me false. And I also tried setting it into component state in my useEffect where I'm watching for isPlaying. The component state updates correctly, but when I reference that state inside of my playSong function it still doesn't get the correct value so I'm just lost at this point.

Comment: Oddly enough too, all of my code used to work just fine before when I had this as a class component. I rewrote all of this using a functional component and hooks since I was refactoring a bunch of code anyways. I find using hooks is much cleaner, but now I'm caught in this issue where I know something small and weird is going on that I'm missing. Just wanted to point that out since that might be relevant to what the underlying issue is.